# ParseFloat output is NaN

Tags: javascript

I've got this javascript code:

```
var id = $(this).attr("class");

var productname = $("td[title='product"+id+"']").html();
var newproductname = parseFloat(productname);
```

HTML:

```
<td class='drinkName' title='product10'>fanta</td>
```

Output is of newproductname is NaN instead of fanta... What is the problem?
I want to have the productname as output.

Comment: Then why are you using `parseFloat`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? If `productname` is `fanta` what should `newproductname` be and why?

Comment: Have you considered trying *7 Up* instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to parse a string which has no valid digits. So, it cannot be converted to a number. That's why `parseFloat` is returning `NaN`.

The arguments to `parseFloat` must always be strings which contain valid digits. You cannot convert `fanta` to a float value, because it has no numbers in it.

From this  **[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)** -

> parseFloat is a top-level function and is not associated with any
>   object.
>
> parseFloat parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point
>   number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -),
>   numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value
>   up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding
>   characters. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.
>
> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat
>   returns NaN.
>
> For arithmetic purposes, the NaN value is not a number in any radix.
>   You can call the isNaN function to determine if the result of
>   parseFloat is NaN. If NaN is passed on to arithmetic operations, the
>   operation results will also be NaN.

The following examples all return `3.14` -

```
parseFloat("3.14");
parseFloat("314e-2"); 
parseFloat("0.0314E+2");
parseFloat("3.14more non-digit characters");
```

The following example returns `NaN` -

```
parseFloat("FF2");
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `fanta` is not a number o_O

Answer (score 3):

parsefloat expects a number like 2.2 or 5. fanta is not a number hence `NAN` which stands for `not a number`